# Is the priest aware of Poco's true nature?

Tags: pocos-udon-world

When Poco visits the shrine, the priest warns Souta of a shapeshifting tanuki. His remark that the tanuki must be lonely is a driving factor for Souta to adopt Poco.

Is the priest aware that Poco **is** the shapeshifting tanuki?

Comment: I believe the priest is aware that Poco is more than he appears.  We will likely find out for sure next week, with the final episode of the season.

Comment: BTW, I believe you have misspelled Poco as "Poko", both in your two questions and the tag.  I have suggested correcting the tag in a [meta forum post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/should-the-tag-for-pocos-udon-world-be-changed-to-correct-its-spelling) .

Comment: @RichF I thought maybe because kana is romanized with a K? Either way, thanks for the input. I sometimes missspell bad.